# DataBase updation message repeatedly coming in wordpress

Tags: wordpress-theming

I am getting Database update message continuously like below

```
Database Update Required

WordPress has been updated! Before we send you on your way, we have to   update your database to the newest version.

The update process may take a little while, so please be patient.

Update WordPress Database
```

I have searched for it and found that a broken theme may be the cause of that. My theme is also showing message that

```
The parent theme is missing. Please install the "Template" parent theme.
```

This message is surprising for me Because I am not using child theme. I haven't mentioned anything about parent theme in my style.css.

But one time parent theme issue resolved on its own for few seconds But after that it starts giving message again. I have no idea why it is happening.

Comment: Now, you have using(Kept ) child theme folder or not?

Comment: I don't have any child theme folder. I am working on custom theme(Without inheritance).